# How do I pass values from a drop down box to an SQL database, using the following code...[error in code]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, code-behind

I am attempting to pass the selectedItem of Drop1.text (DropDownList) through to save in an SQL table (TimeSheetDtls) in the Emp_Name field and at the moment, the code below is not working. When I click on the button (button1_click added to the button already), the page posts back but doesn't update the table or write out a thank you statement. Where is the error?

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = Drop1.Text; // Scrub user data

    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TimesheetDtlsConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection Conn = null;
    try
    {
        Conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        Conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = Conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TimeSheetDtls VALUES (@Emp_Name)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp_Name", Drop1.SelectedItem);
            int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rowsAffected == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("Thank you very much, " + Drop1.SelectedItem); //Success notification
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("There was an error, please try again."); //Error notification
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log error 
        //display friendly error to user
    }
    finally
    {
        if ( Conn != null)
        {
           Conn.Close(); //cleanup connection i.e close 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove your empty catch so that you can see any exceptions.

Comment: Yes, it may be swallowing the exception.

Comment: Is the first field of the TimeSheetDetls table the Emp_Name?

Comment: Is it guaranteed to be unique??

Comment: It's a combination of firstName & lastName and there's sub 20 employees...so I guess it will be, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Drop1.SelectedValue` instead...

For working locally try the following format for your connection string:

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" 
    connectionString="Initial Catalog=MyDB;Data Source=MyMachineName;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

For the remote server use:

```
<remove name="MyConn" />
    <add name="MyConn" 
        connectionString="server=MyServerName;database=MyDB;uid=MyAdmin;pwd=MyPwd"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Remove the try/catch and see what happens (just to test)

Comment: IrishChieftain, thank you, that made a change. It now redirects and tells me..."System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "TimesheetDtls" requested by the login. The login failed."

The web.config file contains the UID and password fields for the connection though...

Comment: There's your prob. Updating my answer :)

Comment: IrishChieftain, thank you, although I'm not working locally, I'm sending the values to a remote database server (this app will be company wide)

Comment: Updating answer but you may need to confirm UN/PW with your admin for the server.

Comment: Thanks again, I am the DBA for that server (it's a VM I created for this app) so I just need to *play* around with the roles and permissions it seems.

Comment: Heads-up: always leave error handling to the very end when writing your code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Or    `Drop1.SelectedItem.Text` if you really want the text.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibility.

1. If you want t insert selected text of `dropdownlist` then use:

   ```
   Drop1.SelectedItem.Text
   ```
2. If you want to insert value of selected text then use:

   ```
   Drop1.SelectedItem.Value
   ```